# Cannot upgrade system from 22.04 to 22.10

Tags: apt, upgrade

Neither the GUI nor the command line will let me do this upgrade.  From the command line I try

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

Prior to this, I have done `sudo apt update` and installed available updates. How can I find out what the system doesn't like?

There is also weird behavior from the GUI-based upgrader.  I launch Software Updater and get this:

[image]

If I then click "Upgrade ..." the Software Updater window goes away and nothing visible happens.

Alternatively, another method for getting this done?

Updated with requested output:

```
$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for scohen: 
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome-remote-desktop/deb stable InRelease                            
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                      
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]                              
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [108 kB]                           
Hit:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu jammy InRelease                          
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                           
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome-remote-desktop/deb stable Release        
Hit:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/bitseater/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease     
Hit:11 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mutlaqja/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Fetched 218 kB in 2s (93.9 kB/s)                           
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fuseiso gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2 gconf2-common libgconf-2-4
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  gnome-remote-desktop libgphoto2-6 libgphoto2-port12
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.

$ do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

Update #2.  Saw this in the above output and tried it.  It made no difference.

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  fuseiso gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2 gconf2-common libgconf-2-4
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 6 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
After this operation, 8,779 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 411977 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing fuseiso (20070708-3.2build1) ...
Removing gconf2 (3.2.6-7ubuntu2) ...
Removing gconf-service-backend (3.2.6-7ubuntu2) ...
Removing gconf-service (3.2.6-7ubuntu2) ...
Removing libgconf-2-4:amd64 (3.2.6-7ubuntu2) ...
Removing gconf2-common (3.2.6-7ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for sgml-base (1.30) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...

$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 will become unsupported in a few months, whereas Ubuntu 22.04 will be supported until 2027. Is there any particular reason you need to upgrade? Otherwise, I will suggest you to not upgrade.

Comment: You need to hurry, 23.04 is already released and 22.10 will become unsupported.

Comment: I want to upgrade to 22.10 as an intermediate step to going to 23.04.

Comment: Wouldn't ```sudo aptitude safe-upgrade``` install the withheld packages without marking them as manually installed?

Comment: @EHJ I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you are getting during the release upgrade attempts are letting you know that you need to update your system before you can upgrade to the next release.

However your package manager is giving errors about held back packages when you try to update.

You also have several PPAs on your system and sometimes PPAs can be incompatible in ways that will hold up the package manager. If you remove the PPAs it might resolve the held back package issues.

The release upgrade script is going to disable your PPAs anyway so if removing the PPAs fixes the problem, that's probably the best path forward.

If the held packages aren't in any way related to the PPAs, you can manually install the packages that are held back. Just note that this will mark those packages as manually installed, which might not be desirable.